# Condition on MYSQL DATETIME column not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I don't have much experience with MySQL so not sure if it's issue with MySQL or my code.

I have a table lets say `data` and it has a `created_at` column of DATETIME type.
This table gets 20-30 new records per second, no updates at all.

I have a Cron job that runs every 15 minute and tries to get all records created in the last 15 minutes.

if it runs at 10:15:06am and the last run was at 10:00:03, it makes this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `data`  WHERE (created_at >= '2021-07-30T10:00:03Z' AND created_at < '2021-07-30T10:15:06Z')
```

Current time is excluded, hence the `created_at < current_time`.

But the problem is, once in a while I get duplicate data error. That is it includes a few data rows from the current_time, which should have been excluded.

Like in this case, if 15 records were inserted at 10:15:06, the query result might have 4-5 records included in it. But it does not happen every time.

I am using Golang and for current time, I use `time.Now()`. Can this be because of millisecond or something else ? I am not making more than 1 database query, so I think it has to do something with DB, if I have extra records.

Comment: can you add the table structure and sample data ?

Comment: Can you share more details? Are these records inserted with `created_at = 10:15:06Z`? Then they should not be returned by this query.

Comment: remove the fractions of time and use only the senconds

Comment: @HarshGundecha The table's other column does not matter as I only make the query by created_at column which is DATETIME type. What else info you need ?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes that is created same way, created_at is always current time, when I insert the record.

Comment: @nbk , I did not understand which fraction you are talking about ?

Comment: you get microseconds in your times, so remove them

Comment: @nbk I have posted the query as it is. Except for the changed table name. '2021-07-30T10:15:06Z' this is the exact time posted the log. which part is microsecond in this ? I don't see anything. or you are talking about langugaes's time.Now() call ?

Comment: please supply a fiddle with the data in question where this doesn't work also add the exact version of the database

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ffe8926723c63c53f07ec99a69f5b69).

Comment: @wchiquito  it fails only 5-7 times out of 100 in my case too. The query that returns extra data, if I run that again, it works fine, so I am not able to reproduce it myself consistently, that is why I did not expect any fiddle to reproduce the issue. I am using MySQL 5.7, probably it's a issue which has been fixed in the newer versions, but sadly I can't upgrade.